# How to put a delay that stops the code without stop the HTML render?

Tags: javascript, html, delay, settimeout, sleep

I need to stop my code in a for loop, a `sleep()` function that stalls time does not work because my HTML does not render in that time and a `setTimeout` function will continue the loop before doing the set code.

For example, this will display alerts with 1,2,3 before 3 alerts with Stop.

```
function test(){
  for (var i = 1;i<4;i++) {
    alert(i);
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Stop");},1000);
  }
}
```

How could I wait until continuing with my loop while letting the HTML render ?

Comment: You should look into an Asynchronous solution, besides setTimeout. `Element.onload = function(){/* other code here */ }` or `var pre = onload; onload = function(){if(pre)pre(); /* other code here */}`

Comment: Are you saying that you want alert(1) then alert("Stop") to show first. Then after some time delay, alert(2) then alert("Stop") to show next. And so on until alert(4) and alert("Stop") to show last?

Comment: How do I use these asynchronous functions ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOMContentLoaded event to check once your HTML is fully rendered:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    alert('html loaded');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I used global variable and a `while` loop to implement this event handler but the loop goes infinite. I set `rendering=true` and do nothing `while (rendering){} ` in my function and set `rendering=false` in the event handler. Do you have any idea to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could instead just use [confirm](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) instead to show a message, and when the user clicks then you use the next `setTimeout` to show the next message.

But, I think this is not what you are actually looking for.

There are many ways to do asynchronous javascript that doesn't impact html rendering, such as using Web Workers, or pass functions inside of `setTimeout` and those can use closures to help track where you are, but, have the next `setTimeout` be called after some processing, and after some event, as these will allow the rendering to continue until certain events or time happens.